# Is there any object model candy in php?

Tags: php

For instance, in vb.net, I can add attributes to the field like this

```
Public Class Chocolate
    <Description("How much milk??"), NonSerialized()>
    Public Milk as Integer = 5
End Class
```

Which greatly aids in automatic handling of different objects since for example, on UI side I can loop through the objects fields and add a tooltip to display that description or on the system side, I can now have temporary fields in an object that don't get serialized should it be saved, etc.

I've even made use of that kind of workflow in javascript since you can do this for instance:

```
var chocolate = function() {
    this.milk = 5;
    this.milk.description = "How much milk??";
}
```

Is there anything like that in php?

Comment: Your question is whether you can dynamically add attributes to objects on PHP?

Comment: no, its about whether or not I can add attributes to object fields

Comment: And what is an object "field"? Objects have attributes and methods. You can add whatever you like to attributes. You can create methods that add stuff to attributes. Options are endless. You can have `$object->addAttribute('field_name', 'field_value');` and so on. It's easier if you'd produce some php code and show us what exactly you had in mind, and then we can steer you in right direction.

Comment: @Mjh Again, that is not what I'm asking. A field is what you call a class member that is a direct reference to a variable (as opposed to a property with getter/setter for example). Attributes generally refer to meta data all though the term is often mistakenly used interchangeably with various member terminology since in some languages the line is rather blurry. A field attribute means metadata about the field, most OO capable languages have some form of it available to aid in template programming.

Comment: OK, if that's not what you're asking, then I wish you all the best and I hope you get the help you're after.